# Conditional Ifelse based on Rule for Employee Hierarchy

Tags: r, hierarchy

This might seem an easy problem but I am unable to hang around this.

I have a data where a person receives feedback from his peer where he can receive from his team member or his peer. In case if manager received feedback from team member, another column must have **upward** as category. If the manager has given it to his team member, the column must have **downward** elseif its from peer to peer with different managers, it must have **Lateral**

My Data looks like this:

```
Employee    ReceivedFrom    EmpDirector
Jake         Frazer         Frazer
Smith        Frazer         Frazer
Frazer       Jake           Alister
Drapper      Frazer         Alister
```

You can see that an *Jake* has received from *Frazer* while *Jake's* director is also *Frazer* and hence its **downward**. Also Notice in last row below that *Drapper* and *Frazer* both have same director but the feedback is itself not from Director, hence it is **lateral**

**Results Wanted**

```
Employee    ReceivedFrom    EmpDirector   FeedbackType
Jake         Frazer          Frazer        Downward
Smith        Frazer          Frazer        Downward
Frazer       Jake            Alister       Upward
Drapper      Frazer          Alister       Lateral
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case_when()` in `dplyr` can manipulate multiple condition statements. Before using it, you need to create an auxiliary variable, i.e. `tmp`, to represent the directors of the people from `ReceivedFrom`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(tmp = EmpDirector[match(ReceivedFrom, Employee)],
         FeedbackType = case_when(
           ReceivedFrom == EmpDirector ~ "Downward",
           Employee == tmp ~ "Upward",
           TRUE ~ "Lateral"),
         tmp = NULL) ## you can remove it if you want

#   Employee ReceivedFrom EmpDirector FeedbackType
# 1     Jake       Frazer      Frazer     Downward
# 2    Smith       Frazer      Frazer     Downward
# 3   Frazer         Jake     Alister       Upward
# 4  Drapper       Frazer     Alister      Lateral
```